# Problems using Transaction Scope with different SQL Servers and databases in the same transaction

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

The following method uses the `TransactionScope` object to make uncommitted reads.

The problem appears when using two different SQL Servers in different methods within the same transaction.

```
using var transactionScope = TransactionScopeBuilder.ReadUncommitted();
var cards = await GetCards(Id);

var products = await _netRepository.GetProducts(Id, Module);

var matchedCards = ((INetMatch<result, AssociatedProducts>)this)
                    .MatchClientProducts(cards, products);
transactionScope.Complete();
```

Where `GetProducts` and `GetCards` query to different databases and servers.

The following message appears when invoking the method.

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

Any help is useful, thank you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your implementation , why are you placing a fetch command under a transaction scope in the first place ?  also usually the default transaction Isolation level is Read Committed. Said so Transaction scope wont be evaluated to light weighted transaction for different data sources , this will be like MTS transaction and each data source has to support it in the first place

Comment: Are you `await`ing when calling this function

Answer (score 0):

Transaction scope wont be evaluated to light weighted transaction for different data sources , this will be like MTS transaction therefore you have to make sure that each data source vendor is supporting it, you will need to enable it from each vendor configuration and you need to take a look at the event logs errors

System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. I know you get this kind of exception when a transaction is forced to rollback could be timeout issue or one vendor doesn't accept/support the MTS transaction causing the whole MTS transaction to rollback or some issue with firewall rules in one of the servers. You can use this a clue and take it from there